# TableViewCell in Storyboard keeps setting width and height to 1000x1000 after restarting Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

So Im running into quite a perculiar problem that Im not sure how to go on from here.. I have a table view cell layed out properly and saved to the specifications I wanted with 0 errors showing. Then after I closed out of the project and reopened it, all the objects within my tableview cell just have their widths and heights changed to 1000x1000. Im not sure how to fix this problem as I would imagine this would be painful to have to resize and re position them every time I reopen the project. I was hoping to find some solutions as to what Im doing wrong and how I can prevent this from happening.

[image]